# Installing vinyl flooring on stormy day

Tags: flooring

I'm
Scheduled to have vinyl flooring installed on a stormy day when it's going to absolutely pour rain. If it gets wet while bringing it in from outside, How will this affect the flooring adhering to the sub floor and condition going forward?

Answer (score 1):

Most vinyl is rolled. A quick wipe on the outside it will be fine. The bigger question is will the home be at the correct tempature for the glue or adhesive's to set. Another question is was the sub floor sealed some of these things are more important than a few rain drops. IMHO.